# Node js Application not displays error while uploading images using Cloudinary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, cloudinary

I deployed my node js Application on heroku that uploads images to cloudinary. It runs normally on my local machine but I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined when I run it on heroku. Please help what am I getting wrong here?

```
app.post('/vehicles', multipartMiddleware, (req, res) => {
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.files.image.path,
    { width: 300, height: 300, crop: "limit", tags: req.body.tags, moderation: 'manual', timeout: 60000 }, 
    (err, result) => {
        console.log(result);

        var vehicle = new Vehicle({
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price,
            transmission: req.body.transmission,
            seat_number: req.body.seat_number,
            milleage: req.body.milleage,
            event: req.body.event,
            category: req.body.category,
            //Stores the url in a DB for future use
            image: result.url,
            image_id: result.public_id
        });

        //Creates a new Vehicle and Add to db
        vehicle.save((err, newVehicle) => {
            if (err) {
                res.redirect("/dashboard")
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.redirect("/vehicles")
                // console.log(newVehicle);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

});

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question with the code

Comment: The error implies `result` is null - what do you see in the console.log() output at the top of the callback - is `error` populated instead of `result`?

Comment: No error was populated I could only observe that the result was null.